# simulating handler method with params in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have written a handler method bound to the `onChange` event of `input` element and it takes two params

```
<div className="p-lg-12">
    <InputText
        value={this.state.blog.title}
        id="title"
        placeholder="Blog Title"
        onChange={e =>
            this.handleInput("title", e.target.value)
        }
    />
</div>
```

based on first param I change value of a specific field in an object manage by the state object

```
handleInput(key, value) {
    let blogData = Object.assign({}, this.state.blog);
    blogData[key] = value;
    this.setState({ blog: blogData });
}
```

I'm not able to `simulate` this method in enzyme

```
it("updates blog data with user input", () => {
    const blogEditor = shallow(<BlogEditor />);
    blogEditor
        .find({ placeholder: "Blog Title" })
        .simulate("onChange", ("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));
    expect(blogEditor.state().blog.title).toEqual("x");
});
```

The resulting error is

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "x"
Received: ""

  45 |             .find({ placeholder: "Blog Title" })
  46 |             .simulate("onChange", ("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));
> 47 |         expect(blogEditor.state().blog.title).toEqual("x");
     |                                               ^
  48 |     });
  49 | });
  50 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (resources/js/tests/BlogEditor/BlogEditor.test.js:47:47)
```

so Am I passing the params to the handler method correctly?

Also, It could be the `find` method that doesn't return the right element so far i've tried

- `find('#title')` as `title` is the HTML id
- `find({ placeholder: "Blog Title" })` as this component as 5 Input
  components each with with unique id attribute and placeholder
  property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using simulate on a shallow render, the event handler should be on that node since shallow doesn't propagate normally. Since the test is relevant to `BlogEditor` and not `Input`, I'd recommend using `mount()` instead of `shallow()`.

### EDIT

From the Enzyme docs:

**Common Gotchas**

- Currently, event simulation for the shallow renderer does not propagate as one would normally expect in a real environment. As a result, one must call .simulate() on the actual node that has the event handler set.

More: https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html

Comment: that helped get over this error, thanks! I have a new one now though to take care of :-) will add details

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: ReactWrapper::simulate() event 'onChange' does not exist`

Comment: quite strange `blogEditor
        .find({ placeholder: "Blog Title" }).at(0).
        .simulate("onChange", ("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));` gives the above error while `blogEditor.find("#title").at(0).props().onChange(("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));` works

Answer (score 0):

So two changes, like @shaun-e-tobias rightly mentioned we should use `mount` in this case; and had to add an `at` method since `find` returns an array it seems, updated test to

```
it("updates blog data with user input", () => {
    const blogEditor = mount(<BlogEditor />);
    blogEditor
        .find({ placeholder: "Blog Title" }).at(0).
        .simulate("onChange", ("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));
    expect(blogEditor.state().blog.title).toEqual("x");
});
```

which then gave the error

```
TypeError: ReactWrapper::simulate() event 'onChange' does not exist
```

I'm using wrong argument for `change` event as noticed in `enzyme` docs so then the method that works becomes

```
it("updates blog data with user input", () => {
    const blogEditor = mount(<BlogEditor />);
    blogEditor.find("#title").at(0).simulate("change",("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));
    expect(blogEditor.state('blog').title).toEqual("x");
});
```

Or you can also call the event through props

```
blogEditor.find("#title").at(0).props().onChange(("title", { target: { value: "x" } }));
```